# Being able to read the current audio frame using ffmpeg and python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

Is there a way to be able to read your current position in an audio file using FFmpeg?

I want to make it so my discord bot plays an audio clip and then on exit, it saves the current position and then when it rejoins the VC it can resume at that point. I know how to get it to resume at the correct time using `-ss` but I am not sure how to get the timestamp at the point ti leaves.
Any help would be appreciated :)!

Comment: I have figured out a way I could do it by starting a timer of sorts when you run the command to play the audio but that seems like it would be quite an inefficient solution. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a better way to do it if anyone is interested. if you set a global variable to the time since epoch and set that as `start`, then when the bot is disconnected set the time since epoch to `end`. You can then subtract `start` from `end` and you are left with the amount of time into the audio clip you are. this can then be stored and retrieved at a later date.

Comment: still wondering if there is any ffmpeg specific fix?